# iTunes Connect won't allow me to update the app if I don't include armv6

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

so, I decided to update my app, but the update doesn't include amrv6 (because I used Xcode 4.5 and it uses iOS 6 related features). That is becasue the previous update did include amrv6 becasue it was easy to implement with Xcode 4.4. So, do I need to create n entirely new app, or there is another way ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, any armv6 device is too old to run iOS 6, which means that if you are going to update your app to use iOS 6 features, you shouldn't have to worry about adding armv6 support.

Answer (score 0):

Check your deployment target. If it is low it might trigger iTunes Connect to ask for a binary for devices which support the older iOS.